How to design digital rheostat that can handle 100 mA?
Specification:

Bidirectional current
Output current: 1 uA to 100 mA
Terminals common-mode voltage: +/- 12V
That would be 24 Meg to 240 Ohm if that is possible.
Stability: +/- 1% if possible
Bandwidth: 1 MHz if possible
THD: < 1% if possible
Steps: 1 uA if possible
Has fine and coarse adjustment
Has the ability to interface with microcontroller
General purpose application


I have MCP4725 12-bit DAC, is it viable to turn back-to-back MOSFET into voltage controlled rheostat in this case as per spec?
I also have X9CXXX, MCP4XXXX, and AD840X at hand, but their voltage swing and current output are rather limited.
I'd like to follow the design from Pau Coma Ramirez, but it's designed to be potentiometer instead of rheostat.


One alternative that I might think is just use rheostat with servo attached to it.
I'm stuck. I wonder if there's any better solution?

Added from comments:
It will be used dedicated on remote experimentation, that's why general purpose.
I need the resistance graph to be linear independent of load and source.

Is there any way I could improve my question?

Do you really need a rheostat, or are you looking for a digitally-controllable current source?

@Hearth I need rheostat, I might use it in the middle of circuit. It might be interesting if I could also control the terminal voltages of the current source such that the resistance graph is linear.

Explain your requirements in terms of resistances, if what you need is resistances. Right now, you're taking about current steps and current ranges, which makes it sound like what you need is a current source. What do you mean "in the middle of circuit"?

Digital pots are newbie bait, I think; once one gains a broader understanding of building blocks, circuit design, what's effective and practical and why, they tend to be used very rarely -- in favor of more direct methods, like a multiplying DAC, or sampled/switched systems. Therefore, I have reason to suspect that applies here: you have a problem that "simply needs a pot", but it's done "at power" and so the simplest question seems to be what is quoted. But this is not your actual underlying problem.

Thus, this appears to be an X-Y problem: you ask about proposed solution Y to problem X, but you would do better to ask about underlying problem X in the first place, or at least give it as background information, a context in which to solve problem Y. But more likely, a new solution Z will be found, and we would rather find that instead.

Making a digital floating rheostat (both terminals at arbitrary potentials) is probably the most complicated way to solve your problem. Even a grounded rheostat would be simpler to do (one end at a fixed potential, doesn’t need to be ground). Please edit the question and tell us what problem you are actually trying to solve. It’s likely a rheostat may not the the best solution even if it seems simple.

@Hearth The terminal voltage could be +/- 12V and the current could be 1 uA to 100 mA, so the range could be from 24Meg to 240 Ohm.

@Unknown123 That's a very wide range. Are you sure there isn't some other way to do what you want?

@TimWilliams It's not an X-Y problem, because it will be used dedicated on remote experimentation, that's why general purpose. It's just that I couldn't find a module that is ready-made high-power interfaceable one online that I seems need to design myself. I need the resistance graph to be linear independent of load and source.

@Hearth It's fine if you could compromise to lower the spec such as into 1 Meg to 100 Ohm and +/- 12V such that I might need add to add resistor in series to limit the current.  The broad range I think might suggest some kind of coarse and fine adjustment circuitry.

I think the most sensible way to do what you're proposing is a servo attached to a conventional potentiometer. I'm not convinced it's not an x-y problem either, honestly. I have no idea what "used dedicated on remote experimentation" means.

The reason you haven't found any such device on offer, is because it's highly impractical: the effort and expense required far outpaces the value of its use.  The next closest thing you might find is a SMU (source measure unit) -- a fairly advanced piece of test equipment, but can be configured in an equivalent way. But probably nowhere near close to 1MHz. BTW, note that 24M at 1MHz is about 7fF -- no active device exists that can implement such a characteristic, and it's ponderous what you would need such for.

Would you please clarify the comments that were moved into your question?
